# In a triangle $ABC$, $AB = a-b$ and $BC = 2\sqrt{ab}$, then find $\angle B$?

Tags: triangles

Is this question solvable?

> In $\Delta ABC$, $AB = a-b$ and $BC = 2\sqrt{ab}$, then $\angle B$ is
>
> (a) $\: 60^{\circ}$
>
> (b) $\: 30^{\circ}$
>
> (c) $\: 90^{\circ}$
>
> (d) $\: 45^{\circ}$

Comment: There is still enough freedom to have various (if not all) possible angles.

Comment: is this correct: $$BC=\sqrt{ab}$$?

Comment: is there another condition?

Comment: BC = 2 root of (ab) as per the question. No other condition is given. I was wondering if this can solved with the given information.

Comment: can we use $$AC=b$$?

Comment: Can the angle B be derived if we use AC = b. There are no more conditions given in the question. So I think any value of AC can be assumed so long as the value of angle B can be derived. I do not know how to solve it. That why I asked.

Comment: As pointed out in an answer, if we use the usual assignment of letters to the lengths of the sides then $a = BC$ and $b = AC$, so the problem statement says $AB = BC - AC$, which implies all the given choices for $\angle B$ are wrong. But if we do not assume $a = BC$ and $b = AC$ then we don't know enough about $a$ and $b$ to rule out any of the choices for $\angle B$. I think either there are clues surrounding this problem that you did not realize should be included, or the problem is a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

What do we know from $\triangle\text{ABC}$:

- $$\angle\text{A}+\angle\text{B}+\angle\text{C}=180^\circ=\pi\space\text{radians}$$
- For the length $\text{AB}$:
  $$\text{AB}=\text{a}-\text{b}$$
- For the length $\text{BC}$:
  $$\text{BC}=2\cdot\sqrt{\text{a}\cdot\text{b}}$$

  ---

Using the law of sinus and the law of cosines:

- $$\frac{\text{BC}}{\sin\left(\angle\text{A}\right)}=\frac{\text{AC}}{\sin\left(\angle\text{B}\right)}=\frac{\text{AB}}{\sin\left(\angle\text{C}\right)}$$
- $$
  \begin{cases}
  \text{BC}^2=\text{AC}^2+\text{AB}^2-2\cdot\text{AC}\cdot\text{AB}\cdot\cos\left(\angle\text{A}\right)\\
  \text{AC}^2=\text{BC}^2+\text{AB}^2-2\cdot\text{BC}\cdot\text{AB}\cdot\cos\left(\angle\text{B}\right)\\
  \text{AB}^2=\text{BC}^2+\text{AC}^2-2\cdot\text{BC}\cdot\text{AC}\cdot\cos\left(\angle\text{C}\right)
  \end{cases}
  $$

So, using your information (and $\left(2\cdot\sqrt{\text{a}\cdot\text{b}}\right)^2=4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{b}$):

- $$\frac{2\cdot\sqrt{\text{a}\cdot\text{b}}}{\sin\left(\angle\text{A}\right)}=\frac{\text{AC}}{\sin\left(\angle\text{B}\right)}=\frac{\text{a}-\text{b}}{\sin\left(\angle\text{C}\right)}$$
- $$
  \begin{cases}
  4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{b}=\text{AC}^2+\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)^2-2\cdot\text{AC}\cdot\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)\cdot\cos\left(\angle\text{A}\right)\\
  \text{AC}^2=4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{b}+\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)^2-2\cdot\left(2\cdot\sqrt{\text{a}\cdot\text{b}}\right)\cdot\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)\cdot\cos\left(\angle\text{B}\right)\\
  \left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)^2=4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{b}+\text{AC}^2-2\cdot\left(2\cdot\sqrt{\text{a}\cdot\text{b}}\right)\cdot\text{AC}\cdot\cos\left(\angle\text{C}\right)
  \end{cases}
  $$

Answer (score 0):

Setting $c=AB=a-b$ gives a degenerate triangle. If there is no relationship between the sides and $a$,$b$,$c$ others than stated any solution is possible. There is a lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

Using @JanEerland ‘s suggestion, $BC = k \sin A$, $AC = k \sin B$, and $AB = k \sin C$; for some $k \ne 0$.

Substituting in the cosine law (wrt B), we get

$$\sin^2 B = \sin^2 A + \sin^2 C – 2 \sin A \sin C \cos B$$

(There might be others) but one solution of it is $B = 90^0$ and $A$ is then complement to $C$.

Note that, up to this point, the given $AB = a - b$ and $BC = ...$ have not been used. They probably are used to find $AC = … = a + b$ by Pythagoras theorem, and for the checking of triangle inequality (which maybe or maybe not necessary). This is not difficult to do with the help of $a – b \gt 0$.

**However, the notation used in the question is very misleading. This is because according to our common naming convention, for $\triangle ABC$, $BC = a$, $AC = b$ etc. Such confusion can be found in various comments.**